# Regex to match all urls, excluding .css, .js recources

Tags: regex, url

I'm looking for a regular expression to exclude the URLs from an extension I don't like.

For example resources ending with: `.css`, `.js`, `.font`, `.png`, `.jpg` etc. should be excluded.

However, I can put all resources to the same folder and try to exclude URLs to this folder, like:

```
.*\/(?!content\/media)\/.*
```

But that doesn't work! How can I improve this regex to match my criteria?

e.g.

**Match**:

`http://www.myapp.com/xyzOranotherContextRoot/rest/user/get/123?some=par#/other`

**No match**:

`http://www.myapp.com/xyzOranotherContextRoot/content/media/css/main.css?7892843`

Comment: What language and environment?

Comment: java, is it relevant for regex? In Java the example is .*\\/(?!content\\/media)\\/.*

Comment: I think you need to check answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/406230/4519059) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is:

```
^((?!\/content\/media\/).)*$
```

see: https://regex101.com/r/bD0iD9/4

Inspirit by [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, the `?!` negative lookahead doesn't remove any characters from the input.  Add `[^\/]+` before the trailing slash.  Right now it is trying to match two consecutive slashes.  For example:

```
.*\/(?!content\/media)[^\/]+\/.*
```

(**edit**) Second, the `.*`s at the beginning and end match too much.  Try tightening those up, or adding more detail to `content\/media`.  As it stands, `content/media` can be swallowed by one of the `.*`s and never be checked against the lookahead.

**Suggestions**:

1. Use your original idea - test against the extensions: `^.*\.(?!css|js|font|png|jpeg)[a-z0-9]+$` (with case insensitive).
2. Instead of using the regular expression to do this, use a regex that will pull any URL (e.g., `https?:\/\/\S\+`, perhaps?) and then test each one you find with [`String.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)): `if(candidateURL.indexOf('content/media')==-1) { /*do something with the OK URL */ }`

Comment: Can you explain you answer with the concrete reuglar expression?

Comment: Edited answer.  See https://regex101.com/r/sV3uO3/2 - I added `()` around each piece so you can see the matches on the right side under "match information."  The initial `.*` swallows the `content/media` so the lookahead never has the opportunity to check it.